# Best practice for dynamically adding controls through copying existent controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, dockpanel

I have a `TabControl`.
While clicking a button I want to add a new `TabItem`s to the `TabControl`.
Among various techniques I've chosen to create `UserControl` inside of a `DockPanel`.
Everything works fine, except for the location of control on a new TabItem is not 0 and it is
not expanded on the main form resize.
Everything is quite simple.

```
    <TabItem Header="new control">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
           <tc:TabItemTemplate/>
        </DockPanel>
    </TabItem>
```

And TabItemTemplate is also located inside a DockPanel, but it's not docked inside a TabItem. What's the catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using TabControl.ItemTemplate, and bind TabControl.ItemsSource to [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) of ViewModels. When user clicks on a button, add new View Model instance to the collection. Refer to this article for more details: [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: Grand merci, will look at it.